# Protractor is inconsistent in locating elements. How to resolve the locator issue

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor, webstorm

[image]
New to protractor and running into problems. Any help is greatly appreciated!
1. Protractor sometimes locates the element and sometimes doesn't work.

```
    public async clickForgetPasswordLink() {
    let expectedValue  = "Forgot Password";
    let link = await element(by.linkText('Forgot Password?'));
    await browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(link),
        TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 'Unable to locate forgot password link...').then(()=>{
         link.click();
    })
   // await link.click();
    let emailText = link.getAttribute("aria-label");
    await emailText.then((text) => {
        logger.info("Getting forgot password link value:" + text);
        expect(text).toEqual(expectedValue);
        browser.driver.sleep(2000);
    });

}
```

2. I am unable to figure out the root cause of the problem with StaleElementError. In the second suite, I am copy pasting same code but error throws only for 2nd suite not the first suite

Comment: with what element are you having problems? that code snippet doesnt really tell anything on the error above

Comment: I have difficulty in figuring out which line of code has issue as webstorm doesn't give proper stack error trace. But I have a major issue with above code which works mostly but sometimes it cannot click the href link during each iteration. I tried using by.css, by.cssContainingText. It is very inconsistent in clicking the line each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public async clickForgetPasswordLink() {
        let expectedValue  = "Forgot Password";
        try {
            let link = await element(by.linkText('Forgot Password?'));
            await browser.wait(await until.elementToBeClickable(link),
                TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 'Unable to locate forgot password link...').then(()=>{
                browser.driver.sleep(2000);
            });
            await link.getAttribute("aria-label").then((text) => {
                logger.info("Getting forgot password link value:" + text);
                expect(text).toEqual(expectedValue);
            });
            await link.click();
            browser.driver.sleep(2000);
        }catch (e) {logger.error("Exception error caught" + e); }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`stale element` means protractor sees the element. So it does locate it.

stale element happens when you try to `await` an action against multiple elements (20+), like this `await element.all().getText()` so find where you do this and figure out a work around.

---

your code from the snippet could've been much more readable

```
public async clickForgetPasswordLink() {
  let expectedValue  = "Forgot Password";
  let link = element(by.linkText('Forgot Password?'));

  await browser.wait(
    until.visibilityOf(link),
    TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 
    'Unable to locate forgot password link...'
  );
  await link.click();

  let emailText = await link.getAttribute("aria-label");

  logger.info("Getting forgot password link value:" + emailText);
  expect(emailText).toEqual(expectedValue);
  await browser.driver.sleep(2000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing better suggestions to fix the problem. I was able to resolve the stale error.  However, the above code still didn't resolve inconsistency issue. I got an error, emailText is not a function. Below is the working code